# User_ID foreign key NULL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

I am very sure I have got everything right but still the foreign key is NULL

I have USER and WEBSITE as two controllers with following models

USER.rb

```
has_many :websites
```

WEBSITE.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

I have added the user_id foreign key in websites table through migration too and can see it too. The only problem is, when I create WEBSITE, the user_id foreign key is getting saved as NULL instead of the ID of the user

What might be the problem ?

Comment: What code are you using to create the website object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure , may be because you didn't run it properly. Please recheck all this below conditions.

1. user_id must be in website table . To add migration you should run `rails g migration AddUserIdToZombies user_id:integer` and then `rake db:migrate`
2. To ensure the user_id must be there with websites table,put validation.
3. To assign user_id automatically,you should do something like `u = User.find 1` `u.websites.create(attr: 'value')`

FYI :Rails dont use foreign key concept. It means that they dont put link in database. They just provide abstract way of linking models.